# Client() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'conn' and 'addr'

Tags: python

```
import threading
import time

Host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 4444
Recived_Bytes = 1024
Format = 'utf-8'


def Client(conn, addr):
    print(f" New Client Connected : {addr} Connected : ")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        length = conn.recv(Recived_Bytes).decode(Format)
        length = int(length)
        if length:
            msg = conn.recv(length).decode(Format)
            print(f"[Client {addr}says : ]{msg}")
            if msg == "disconnect" or msg == "Disconnect" or msg == "DISCONNECT":
                connected = False
    conn.close()


def start():
    sever.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = sever.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=Client(), args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print("Connection : ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello Zaeem ")
    print(Host)
    ADDR = (Host, port)
    sever = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sever.bind(ADDR)
    start()
```

> Error
> i am facing the error
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "C:/Users/zaeem/PycharmProjects/socketprogramming/main.py", line 40, in 
> > start()
> > File "C:/Users/zaeem/PycharmProjects/socketprogramming/main.py", line 29, in start
> > thread = threading.Thread(target=Client(), args=(conn, addr))
> > TypeError: Client() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'conn' and 'addr'

Comment: `target=Client()` is an immediate call to the function, with no parameters, occurring in the main thread.  You just want `target=Client` to pass the function itself to the Thread.

Comment: Also notice that calling a function `Client` is not great  - most people reading the code and familiar with python would assume that `Client` is a class, since functions are recommended to use `lowercase` or `snake_case`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your Client function in that line - what you need is :

```
  thread = threading.Thread(target=Client, args=(conn, addr))
```

Notice in this you leave off the () after Client - so you aren't trying to call Client, you are simply passing a reference to the Client function.

*As mentioned in my comment - using `Client` as a name is misleading to people who know Python - It is recommended that functions use `lowercase` or `snake_case` - and that capitalized names (so called `CamelCase`) should be used for classes only.*